# What happen if GO BOTTOM & SKIP 3 executes in order?

Tags: database, command, skip

Yesterday I have given an exam in that one question is asked something like this:

We have table named `tbl_demo`, it has `30 records`.

If we give following command in order,

```
GO BOTTOM then SKIP 3
```

What happen if this both command executes in that order ?

`will it came to record number 3rd or 28th` ?

3rd because it will goes bottom then skip 3 will execute so went to 3rd record.

or it will came up to 28th record, go bottom then skip 3, so it at last then skip 3 so no record so back 3 records.

or other thing will happen ?

Anyone have idea that what this command actually do if we execute in given order ?

Comment: Do you refer to a special database system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this general frame you are putting the question into, I'd say this is undefined behaviour.

Common behaviours are to begin again and end up with record 3 or 4 (if 1 is the first record) or throwing an error.

Comment: I have tried to find out this commands in mysql but I don't find so I think it's in oracle, am I right or not ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any positioning commands in any SQL dialect, neither mysql nor oracle. I'd guess, the term was used in the context of your course to illustrate a rather general database system?

Comment: Oh, but it's not course related because it's entrance exam for p.hd students and they ask all question related to IT field, so I also don't know that about actually what they ask ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it 4th record?The GO BOTTOM command shifts the control to the bottom of the database and then the SKIP 3 command skips three records so ultimately the control gets transferred to the 4th record.

Comment: I also don't know. I have 4 options in exam, `1. 28th, 2. 30th, 3. 3rd, 4. 4th`

Answer (score 0):

`GO` Moves the record pointer to the specified record number.

`BOTTOM` Positions the record pointer on the last record in the table. If the table has an ascending index in use, the last record is the record with the highest key value. If the index is in descending order, the last record is the record with the lowest key value.

`SKIP   [nRecords]`

`nRecords:`

Specifies the number of records to move the record pointer.
Issuing SKIP without `nRecords` advances the record pointer to the next record. The record pointer moves toward the end of the file `nRecords` records if `nRecords` evaluates to a positive number. The record pointer moves toward the beginning of the file `nRecords` records if `nRecords` evaluates to a negative number.

here `nRecords` = 3.

Go BOTTOM will go to record no 30. Then SKIP 3 means skipping 30,29,28.

it means the control is now at 27. So the answer is 27.

This question is taken from UGC NET 2013 December paper 2 question no 12. UGC has given official answer i.e. 27.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977827

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978459